# how to add a kb scanner in a println ? and how to make it so the code doesnt go all at once

Tags: java, ide, println

Basically i want it to ask you what your name is, 
so like

```
    System.out.println("Stranger: what is your name?");
    then here like System.out.println("Name:");kb scanner //so i dont have to skip a line
```

and also how would i make it so that after the first dialog you would have to hit space or a key to get the next system.out.println

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Stranger: Good morning");
        System.out.println("Stranger: you had a terrible Dream..");
        System.out.println("Stranger: what is your name?");
        System.out.println("Name:");
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner (System.in); 
        String s = kbReader.next();
        System.out.println("Nice to meet you " + s);
        System.out.println("my name is Master Wizard.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Thanks guys! im sorry im new to this stuff lol, even tho this is basic, my blue pelican book doesnt mention this stuff

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but perhaps what you mean is that you don't want a new line after `System.out.println("Name:");`, and if that is the case all you must do is change it to `System.out.print("Name: ");`.  `println` appends a `\n` character, `print` does not.

The pause can be accomplished by doing `kbReader.next();`, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean to use:

```
System.out.print("Name: ");
String s = kbReader.nextLine(); // better to use nextLine
```

Using `print` instead of `println` will allow the user to type their answer on the same line as the prompt. I'm not sure if I fully understand your question though.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> Thank you this worked ! wish i could vote you, but also how would i make it so all the code doesnt shoot out at once??

You're welcome. To slow down the println's there are several things you could do:

- you could use a java.util.Timer if you want to have each println be called every such and such msecs.
- or for the same thing, use `Thread.sleep(...)`
- or if you want to wait for the user to press enter for the next question, prompt the user for them to do this, and use `kbReader.nextLine()` to pause program flow while waiting ofr the user to respond.

Comment: Thank you this worked ! wish i could vote you, but also how would i make it so all the code doesnt shoot out at once??

Comment: @JordanBrown You could try something like `Thread.sleep(millis)` inbetween the `System.out`s to slow the output.

Comment: well could i make it so that the user hits space or something?

Comment: @JordanBrown: Please see Edit to answer.